# How to leverage authentication outside of WordPress?

Tags: authentication

I have a situation where I would like to authenticate against the WP_users table from outside of WP.

Basically I have username and password fields on a static php page outside of wordpress and need to check user / pass and send back a response (yes / no).

1. Is this possible?
2. Any clues on how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's possible. But I prefer not to give a beginner lesson in brute force attacks.

I recommend you take a look at [wp-api](http://wp-api.org/#users_retrieve-a-user) it uses OAuth Authentication for remote apps. It's the way to go by all means.