# How do I authenticate WP users from a chrome extension?

Tags: security, authentication, google-chrome, oauth

I'm new to WordPress, and I need help. I am writing a chrome extension and intend to use wordpress as the user database. I intend that because I'm using a subscription management WP plugin that keeps our subscription information there on the WP site. I am wanting to use WP authentication to check for subscription status, and subscription status to gate the primary functionality.

I was expecting to build a login form in my chrome extension and securely authenticate with the username and password via https. I'm not seeing that option anywhere. Maybe I'm blind! Instead, I've found:

1. OAuth2: This I have (mostly) working but feels clunky because it isn't embedded into my Chrome extension. It pops open a borderless WP login window. =/
2. Single Sign On: This doesn't help me since I need the user's wordpress identity to assess subscription status.
3. WP API: My understanding is that this wouldn't authenticate each individual user, but just verify access to an API.

   - Oauth: Per WP, this doesn't seem any different (or better) than OAuth2 which is already working.
   - Application passwords: Per WP, these can't be used to login
   - Basic authentication: Per WP,  these are not for use in production.

This [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/207366/how-to-leverage-authentication-outside-of-wordpress) seems identical to mine, but the answer points to the API. Am I missing something in the WP API [authentication documentation](http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/authentication/)?

Can someone tell me how best to pursue this? I need knowledge, not code.

Comment: I'm not familiar with chrome extensions at all, but if you want users to be able to just type their username/password within the extension, you could easily extend the REST API with your own handler that authenticates the user manually (as opposed to OAuth/application keys), and then have the extension POST to the endpoint?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Ok, so I would POST the credentials in a REST request to the REST API endpoint, have my handler perform authentication and return a yay or nay in the REST response? And that'd be very reasonably secure?

Comment: Yep and yep (providing you use HTTPS of course)

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a shot and set a reminder to come update this question (or accept your answer if you make it one).

Comment: I had to overcome a logout issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080632/how-do-i-log-out-of-a-chrome-identity-oauth-provider), but I'm sticking with OAuth2 for the time being.