# How to allow users login to WP from external domain and make REST requests

Tags: wp-admin, login, rest-api, third-party-applications, oauth

Basically what i want to do is:

1. Use Wordpress as a login system and data storage for web-application on another domain.
2. Make users able to register and perform REST calls from the application.
3. Let users manage their accounts and post contents without using wp-admin at all.

For REST Api i found a really nice plugin:
http://v2.wp-api.org/

however after using POST method my wordpress is saying:
"Sorry, you are not allowed to create new posts." - Because I'm not logged in.

REST plugin does allow me to configure App and Secret, but what if i have
1000 users, each with different privilliges. I need a real per-user login system.

Any recommendations will be helpful.

Comment: Have you checked out the [authentication docs](http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/authentication/)?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Yes and I used oAuth method to authorize application through oAuth app secret, but I'm not sure how to make every user able to log-in using their own WP login / password / facebook / gplus.

Comment: [Check this brief discussion](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/225145/1685) - same thing, just another website instead of a chrome extension.

Comment: I've done the exact same thing that you are asking for.
For this I've used a plug-in called 'JWT Authentication for WP-API', it works like a charm. Documentation is available.